# PWA Problems only in Lighthouse "Request was blocked by DevTools"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I can't get Lighthouse to work in Chrome for my first PWA. I've been trying to do this for around 4 hours and I'm just lost. Nothing makes sense. It is extremely basic code that I've included below.

The problem is that when I load the page normally everything works correctly, but when I try to run Lighthouse it hangs and then timesout with the attached image errors. I get no report. Am I doing something stupid? What am I missing?

Note: I added the kill code to ensure there's no duplicate service workers and the like but it doesn't matter if I remove it.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="This is a PWA Test">

    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./se5.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./.webmanifest">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css?1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/luke.js?4"></script>
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
                for(let registration of registrations) {
                    console.log('luke: Killed SW:', registration.scope);
                    registration.unregister()
                }
            })

            navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js?5', {
                scope: './',
                registrationStrategy: "registerImmediately"
            })
            .then(function(registration) {
                console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
            });
        }
        </script>
<body>
    
    <h1>Hello World 3</h1>
    <img src="./images/se_logo_192.png" alt="test">
</body>
<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

sw.js

```
console.log('SW: I am a Service Worker!');

const filesToCache = [
    './styles/main.css',
    './images/se_logo_192.png',
    './images/se_logo_512.png'
];
  
  const staticCacheName = 'pages-cache-v1';
  
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache static assets');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                console.log('SW: Complete!');
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            }
        )
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

.webmanifest

```
{
    "short_name": "short_name",
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "./images/se_logo_512.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      },
      {
        "src": "./images/se_logo_192.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "background_color": "#3367D6",
    "display_override": ["window-control-overlay", "minimal-ui"],
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "./",
    "theme_color": "#3367D6",
    "shortcuts": [

    ],
    "screenshots": [

    ]
}
```

Edit: added pictures of the network filter to show there's nothing there and no options to unblock either.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, for all those with this pain:

Use Microsoft Edge instead.

I know. Apparently it's a cache / profile thing so use another browser or fully clear your cache / log out log in again.

So I am now using Edge for my tests and all works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well and after much grubbing around found that it's because of [a bug in Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13396) that should be fixed in Chrome 97 (release date 4 Jan 2022).

In the meantime there's a workaround - open settings using the cog icon and turn off "Clear storage".

[image]